# How to change the app preference settings through code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, cocos2d-iphone

I have listed my app in the device setting app.Now I can change my app settings through the device app settings app.
Now what I am trying to do is the reverse.
I am trying to make a app so that it can itself change its preferences in the device settings app if I change the preferences of my app from within the app.

Any ideas Friends,
Thank You All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice and simple:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"MyPreferenceKey"];
```

`NSUserDefaults` includes convenience methods for setting ints, floats, strings, and so on. You can also just use -setValue:forKey:.

When you change a value in your app using `NSUserDefaults`, the setting well change in the Settings app, too.